# Mongodb insureIndex error "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:"

Tags: mongodb

I got a geo location field 'loc' where i can't execute a "insureIndex({loc:"2dsphere"}) on. I get the error "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:". There is already indexes in that collection and there is also other fields beside loc. I tested and separated the loc field and put it in a collection by it self, then I was able to run insureIndex. The problem is I can't move the loc field outside that collection. And I need the "2dsphere to be able to run the $near query for nearby locations. Any help/insight is appreciated.

Comment: could it be that there is a malformed object in the collection?  i.e. the problem is with the currently stored data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did find out that there were some null objects in the data stream. I've corrected that with default values. However I haven't been able to test that yet because the system I'm running my tests on is currently overloaded by my colleges. But I'll know soon.